# Wordpress text wrap around image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to do something that I thought would take 2 minutes and instead has taken up 2 hours... When you insert an image into Wordpress, it automatically puts it into a paragraph. I'm trying to get subsequent paragraphs to wrap around the image, and nothing's working for me. My CSS is:

```
p img.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

p {
    float:left;
    clear: none;
}
```

What the heck am I missing?! My html is just:

This is why I'm so peeved - this is what I tried to begin with! It shouldn't need anything really, as Wordpress already has that in the default theme css, and I'm not over-riding it in my custom theme. My html is:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
<p><a href="imgroot"><img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-89" src="imgroot" width="300" height="300" /></a></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML markup as well

Comment: If you're building a custom theme, you need to compensate for not having Wordpress's generated CSS helper classes for captions, images etc, which can be [found here](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS) - add their CSS as needed to your own theme's CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, the following works:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
<p><a href="imgroot"><img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-89" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" width="300" height="300" /></a></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

You just need to float the image to the left (as proven by the runnable code snippet above)...If this doesn't work, share your HTML markup with us.

Comment: This is why I'm so peeved - this is what I tried to begin with! It shouldn't need anything really, as Wordpress already has that in the default theme css, and I'm not over-riding it in my custom theme. My html is:

Comment: Yep - sorry - hadn't realised I couldn't add it into comments - written it above now.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, this also works. You may have another style that's overriding it. I'd use your browser inspector to verify.

Comment: Yep - sorted - I had an errant "display:inline-block" well above... Should have got more sleep! Thanks though.